# Old issue back on iOS 14: Can't set text color of Cancel button in mail composer presented from UIActivityViewController

Tags: swift, ios14

This is a known issue I have faced before but my previous solution is not working on iOS 14, so the white cancel button is invisible against a white background. I have tried alternatives that worked for previous versions, but none work on iOS 14.

This is what used to work and doesn't anymore:

`UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: .black], for: .normal)`

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this?